# Deploying To a Power BI Report Server with PowerShell - failed to create a session

Tags: powershell, deployment, tfs, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I use Rob Sewells's [script](https://blog.robsewell.com/blog/deploying-to-a-power-bi-report-server-with-powershell/).

Script worked very well until, for some reason, it stopped.

TFS failed to create a session
[image: TFS failed to create a session]

I am wondering what could be the reason for this behavior of TFS.
Interestingly, when I run it manually, the same error appears until from the C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Modules\ReportingServicesTools\Functions\Utilities path I re-load the New-RsRestSession function.

when run script locally
[image: when run script locally]

after New-RsRestSession reload
[image: after New-RsRestSession reload]

I don't have much knowledge of how TFS works, I tried to make the function re-load (as I do it manually) as an additional task in the release pipeline in TFS but it didn't help.
I would also add that the release pipeline config in TFS is identical to Rob's.
I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: It is probably a credential issue.  When run locally it give error that you cannot write to the report folder.  Check if the report folder exists

Comment: either in TFS and locally there is the same error. When it comes to folder - if you look into Rob's script - if the folder doesn't exist it is supposed to create itself, if it exists it just puts the file into it

Comment: If you do not have permission to write to folder, it will never be created.

Comment: How can I not have permissions when I can do it from a script locally or directly doing the upload in RS? what's more - my pool agent too - after all he was doing it so far

Comment: Did you start PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin?  It probably means when you do it from a script locally you have permission and do not have permission when it fails.  You are either using a differ account, you are not an admin, or you are going through a gateway (proxy) that is using a different credentials.

Comment: script runs locally whether I run it as admin or not

Comment: Is it failing using a Service?  If so have service start with a Server account.  The default is a system account.  It work locally which implies it is failing remotely.  I do not see when a remote access is being performed.  Error would indicate when executing remotely that different privileges (credentials) are being used.

Comment: It is failing using my one and only user account, based on that I have agent pool created and via it every process in TFS is being lunched. I think that since locally before refreshing the New-RsRestSession function I get the same error as in TFS then what you are saying doesn't make much sense

Comment: New-RsRestSession is making a web connection and is not in the same domain (or credentials) as when code is working.  See following : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools/0.0.2.8/Content/Functions%5CUtilities%5CNew-RsRestSession.ps1